# В консоли не получается выйти на установленный python, выводится python из среды anaconda

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda, virtualenv, version

Всем здравствуйте!

У меня возникла такая проблема:
Установлен python версии 3.9.1 по следующему пути: `C:\Python3.9.1(64-bit)\python.exe`, также в переменные среды User в PATH были добавлены пути: `C:\Python3.9.1(64-bit)\Scripts\`, `C:\Python3.9.1(64-bit)`. Недавно установила Anaconda.

И теперь когда в консоли я пишу python, то получаю следующее сообщение:
[image]

Возможно пути до anaconda добавленные в path системных переменных мешают?

Помогите выйти на python 3.9. Буду рада любой помощи! Если что-то нужно пояснить или дополнить, то пишите:)

Comment: Это может произойти если вы вызываете анаконда-питон вне активированной среды, возможно что у вас анаконда-питон находится в переменных среды.

Comment: Самый простой но не самый удобный вариант `C:\Python3.9.1(64-bit)\python.exe MyScript.py` а вообще в анаконде вроде при установке советуют не ставить галочку с добавлением ее в патч. Если не сильно критично можно все переустановить.